# Как обработать параметры, что пришли от клиента на сервер python flask

Tags: python, http, flask

Очень прошу помочь с вопросом: как же всё же мне обработать полученные параметры от пользователя.

История такова, есть л.сервер на flask, что должен принимать данные, как их передать с клиента python или js я понял. но вот как мне их обработать на сервере ?
Старался, но информацию не нашёл хотя вопрос крайне лёгкий.

Допустим, мы принимаем данные от клиента:

```
params = {"rgbMod": "redWave", "cpuTemp": "63", "gpuTemp": "66"}
get = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:9271/data", params= params)
```

flask сервер

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
  

@app.route('/data', methods=['GET'])
def get_json():
    return "Ok" 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=9271)
```

Что я должен прописать в flask ?
как мне обработать значения параметров?

Извиняюсь, что потратил ваше время на такой лёгкий вопрос, очевидно, что ответ есть в документации

Answer (score 0):

Как и большая часть вопросов неопытного программиста - ответ на вопрос был на поверхности и не сложен в реализации.

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['GET'])
def data():
    rgbMod = request.args.get('rgbMod')
    print(rgbMod)
    return "Ok"
```